# Population density within polygons

Tags: r, spatial, raster, shapefile

So, I have some questions regarding the raster package in R. I have a raster with estimated population in each grid point. I also have a shapefile with polygons of regions. I want to find out the coordinates of the neighborhood with the highest population density within each regions. Supose that each neighborhood is a homogeneous square of 5 by 5 grid points.

The following toy example mimics my problem.

```
library(raster)
library(maptools)

set.seed(123)

data(wrld_simpl)

wrld_simpl <- st_as_sf(wrld_simpl)
contr_c_am <- wrld_simpl %>%
  filter(SUBREGION ==13) %>%
  filter(FIPS != "MX") %>%
  select(NAME) 


# Create a raster of population (sorry for the bad example spatial distribution)
r <- raster(xmn=-180, xmx=180, ymn=-90, ymx=90, res=0.1)
values(r) <- runif(ncell(r), 0, 100)

# keep only raster around the region of interest
r_small <- crop(r, extent(contr_c_am))
plot(r_small)
plot(st_geometry(contr_c_am), add = T)

raster_contr_c_am <- rasterize(contr_c_am, r)
```

raster_contr_c_am is the population grid and the name of the region is saved as an attribute.

Somehow I need to filter only grid points from one region, and probably use some funcion like focal() to find total nearby population.

```
focal(raster_contr_c_am, matrix(1,5,5),sum, pad = T, padValue = 0)
```

Then, I need to find which grid point has the highest value within each region, and save it's coordinates.

I hope my explanation is not too confusing,

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example that iterates over the shape defining the region, then uses the raster values within the region and the `focal()` function to find the maximum.

```
library(raster)
library(maptools)
library(sf)
library(dplyr)

set.seed(123)

data(wrld_simpl)

wrld_simpl <- st_as_sf(wrld_simpl)
contr_c_am <- wrld_simpl %>%
    filter(SUBREGION ==13) %>%
    filter(FIPS != "MX") %>%
    select(NAME) 

# Create a raster of population (sorry for the bad example spatial distribution)
r <- raster(xmn=-180, xmx=180, ymn=-90, ymx=90, res=0.1)
values(r) <- runif(ncell(r), 0, 100)

# keep only raster around the region of interest
r_small <- crop(r, extent(contr_c_am))
raster_contr_c_am <- rasterize(contr_c_am, r_small)

# function to find the max raster value using focal
# in a region 
findMax <- function(region, raster) {
    tt <- trim((mask(raster, region))) # focus on the region
    ff <- focal(tt, w=matrix(1/25,nc=5,nr=5))
    maximumCell <- which.max(ff) # find the maximum cell id
    maximumvalue <- maxValue(ff) # find the maximum value
    maximumx <- xFromCell(ff, maximumCell) # get the coordinates
    maximumy <- yFromCell(ff, maximumCell)
    # return a data frame
    df <- data.frame(maximumx, maximumy, maximumvalue)
    df
}

numberOfShapes <- nrow(contr_c_am)
ll <- lapply(1:numberOfShapes, function(s) findMax(region = contr_c_am[s,], raster = r_small))
merged <- do.call(rbind, ll)
maxpoints <- st_as_sf(merged, coords=c('maximumx', 'maximumy'), crs=crs(contr_c_am))

library(mapview) # optional but nice visualization - select layers to see if things look right
mapview(maxpoints) + mapview(r_small) + mapview(contr_c_am)
```

I've made an `sf` object so that it can be plotted with the other spatial objects. Using the `mapview` package, I get this.

[image]